# Android add data to GridView, UI loading no action

Tags: android, android-gridview

I'm calling parse, after fillData to `GridView`.
I've added loading widget (mProgressBar), but it shows once time and hold view.

After I got success data, UI loads again. After loading data, mProgressBar is hang. Can you help me? Thanks. 
Code :

```
 private void loadData() {
        // initialize your items array
        mapDownloadAdapter = new MapDownloadAdapter(this);
        lvShopMapDownload.setAdapter(mapDownloadAdapter);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //show progress_loading .
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final LevelMapProvider imageTypeProvider = new LevelMapProvider(getApplication());
                imageTypeProvider.getAllLevelMap(new LevelMapProvider.IGetAllLevelMapsCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGetAllLevelMapsSuccess(final List<LevelMapModel> levelMapModels) {
                        final MapProvider mapProvider = new MapProvider(getApplication());
                        mapProvider.getAllMap(new MapProvider.IGetAllMapCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onGetAllMapLevelsSuccess(final List<MapDownloadModel> mapModels) {
                                if (mapModels.size() >0){
                                LocalStorage.getSharedInstance(getApplication()).saveListMapDownloaded(mapModels);
                                }

//                                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                                mapDownloadAdapter.fillData(mapModels);

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTaskFailure(final int statusCode,
                                                      final String errorMessage) {
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTaskFailure(int statusCode,
                                              String errorMessage) {

                    }
                });

            }
        });

        //check internet.
        if (!CommonUtil.isInternet(this)) {
            mTvMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mTvMessage.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.text_message_no_connection));
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you fill data to any view like listview or gridview, if data is too large then your view can be stuck. So better to be use any text like "Please wait.." rather than progressbar. So in your XML put textbox in place of progressbar, then after you can hide or view as per your requirement.